# Strpos offset in PHP not working as expected?

Tags: php, unit-testing

I've been pulling my hair for hours for this. I'm trying to find all the positions of `iframe` The first occurrence is successful but not the second one.

Here's my code

```
$ofAllIFrames = qp( $this->content, 'iframe' );

    $iframes = array();
    $allIframes = array();
    $startTag = 0;
    foreach( $ofAllIFrames as $iframe) {
        $startCurrentTag = strpos( $this->content, '<iframe>', $startTag );
        $endCurrentTag = strpos( $this->content, '</iframe>', $startTag );
        $iframes[] = array(
            'start' =>  $startCurrentTag,
            'end'   =>  $endCurrentTag
        );
        $allIframes[] = $iframe;
        $startTag = $endCurrentTag;
        var_dump($startTag);
        ob_flush();

    }
    return array(
        'hasIFrame' =>  count( $allIframes ) > 0,
        'elements'  =>  $iframes
    );
```

And this is my test case

```
public function test_if_content_has_multiple_iframes() {
        $content = 'some content <iframe></iframe> <iframe id="1"></iframe> and another content';
        $iframeChecker = new IFrame_Checker( $content );

        $params = $iframeChecker->check();

        $this->assertTrue( $params['hasIFrame'] );
            $this->assertEquals( 13, $params['elements'][0]['start'] );
        $this->assertEquals( 21, $params['elements'][0]['end'] );   

            $this->assertEquals( 31, $params['elements'][1]['start'] );
        $this->assertEquals( 46, $params['elements'][1]['end'] );   
    }
```

And the test failed for the second iframe

```
1) Test_IFrame::test_if_content_has_multiple_iframes
Failed asserting that false matches expected 31.
```

Comment: Whats the point of `$iframes[]` and `$alliframes[]`?  Seems like an unnecessary level of nesting.

Comment: the code might not be in the best position I just hack something together without refactoring it. They can be deleted once I'm able to get the starting  and ending position.

Comment: What I was wondering was that why setting offset for the second element is not working as it returns `false` for not finding the second element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $startCurrentTag = strpos( $this->content, '<iframe>', $startTag );
    $endCurrentTag = strpos( $this->content, '</iframe>', $startCurrentTag );
```

Should work better.

Reason:

*$startTag* equals *$endCurrentTag* from the previous loop which refers to the offset at `</iframe>...`.  So this is going to return the same position if you use `$endCurrentTag = strpos( $this->content, '</iframe>', $startTag );`